# Using Automapper to map a property of a collection to an array of primitives

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

Given the following set of classes:

```
class Parent
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<Child> children { get; set; }
}
class Child
{
     short ChildId { get; set; }
     string Name { get; set; }
}

class ParentViewModel
{
      string Name { get; set; }
      short[] ChildIds { get; set; }
}
```

When I call

```
Mapper.Map<Parent, ParentViewModel>(vm);
```

Is it possible to get AutoMapper to translate the list of `Child.ChildId` to `ParentViewModel.ChildIds`?

I've tried doing something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Child, short>()
    .FromMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ChildId));
Mapper.CreateMap<Parent, ParentViewModel>()
    .FromMember(dest => dest.ChildIds, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new[] {src.children}));
```

But I get an error saying it doesn't know how to convert a list of Child objects to an int16.   Any suggestions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use a LINQ query to grab just the ChildIds:

```
.ForMember(d => d.ChildIds, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Children.Select(c => c.ChildId).ToArray()));
```

Comment: OMG this was super useful!

Comment: Nice. And there's no need for a .ToArray()